# Странное использование суффикса -то

Tags: значения

В школе меня учили, что с помощью суффикса -то образуются неопределённые местоимения, например

> где - where; где-то - somewhere

Но недавно я в книжке увидел такие примеры использования:

> Внешне баба Тома была похожа на классическую русскую бабушку, но **я-то** знал, что была у неё за плечами какая-то непростая судьба.
>
> У **нас-то** мир и спокойствие, мы нужны всем!
>
> **Ничего-то** нам было не известно
>
> Глаза наши давно привыкли к подземельям, где света не то что не было, а просто он был так же редок, как чистая вода: **вообще-то** вроде бы и есть, но поди найди хороший источник, подземный ручей, наладь от него трубу, обеспечь стоки… Хорошего специалиста по канализации могли выменять на десяток снайперов.

(В. Березин, *Путевые знаки*)

Ни в одном из примеров я не знаю, как перевести это *-то*. Что значит оно в этих примерах и с какой целью оно используется?

Comment: Вообще-то, `как-то` и `где-то` - здесь `-то` не частица, а суффикс.

Comment: It's a suffix in _где-то_, _кто-то_, as UVV mentioned, but a particle elsewhere in your examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Есть две такие уточняющие частицы, <kbd>то</kbd> и <kbd>же</kbd>.

Зная, что автор имеет родным языком польский, я приведу примеры из польского:

```
     Właśnie na to   należy położyć nacisk.
     Именно на это  нужно  сделать упор.
         \
      исключив "именно",
      то же самое скажем
      по-русски:
             \
  Вот на это-то и нужно сделать упор.
```

Прямые аналогии в польском:

```
   a dalej to już ...
   а дальше-то, уже ...

   jako to ...
   как-то ...

   A na wozach cóż to wieziecie, jeśli wolno spytać?
                   /
                  /
   А на телегах-то что везете, позвольте спросить?
```

---

В английском параллели еще проще. Это артикли `the` и `a/an`.
Пусть мы имеем предложение (1):

**1.** Оно звучит так, как будто мы рассказываем сказку, или анекдот:

```
  В одном парке стоит дом ...
  A house stands in a park ...
```

Теперь мы хотим сказать следующее:

**2.** Мы видели или слышали <kbd>об этом</kbd> доме раньше, и тут
  мы видим, что <kbd>этот (именно этот)</kbd> дом по-прежнему 
  стоит, в том же парке, и тогда мы говорим, используя частицу `то`=`the`:

```
  
  Дом-то стоит в парке!
      /
     /
   The house stands inside the park.
```

**или,** Нам сообщили, что дома (уже) в парке нет. Конечно, мы видели или слышали о доме раньше. И тут мы видим, что <kbd>этот (именно этот)</kbd> дом 
по-прежнему стоит, в том же парке, и тогда мы удивленно говорим, используя частицу `же`=`the` :

```
  Дом же стоит в парке!
  The house stands inside the park!
```

Comment: `The house stands inside the park.` я бы перевёл как `Этот дом стоит в парке`. По крайней мере это моя первая мысль.

Comment: @marmistrz , (1) если я спрошу **А как тогда переведём-то?**, то я спросил о переводе именно того, на что мы оба однозначно сможем указать. (2) **А как тогда переведем** *'This house stands inside the park.'*? Видите разницу? В (2) непонятно, о чем речь, если не продолжить. (3) Местоимение-прилагательное `этот` будет слишком сильным. Разница как раз укладывается в разницу между `This` и `The`. Мы не доопределяем дом среди других, вводя прилагательное `этот`. Мы просто показываем уточняющей частицей слушателю, что он знает, о чем речь. Эти две частицы есть самый точный эквивалент для `the`.

Comment: @Avtokod: Akvokod, that explanation is epic. That is the first time anyone has managed to make me understand this elusive particle even on bit. Thank you! Now it seems so simple.

Comment: I admit that's a nice parallel yet as any made explanation it can't be truly exact. For example, "Хорошо-то как!" - how to translate it in English using "the"? The problem is that "the" applies only to a noun, while "-то" virtually to anything.

Comment: @user4419802 , We must evaluate *"хорошо как"* и *"хорошо-то как"*, to judge the difference indefinite / definite. Without a context, the first  seems an elliptical construction, not full sentence. The second is more distinct, therefore, clearly in line with my claim.

Comment: Yes, they both about distinctions yet about _different_ disctinctions. "The" is purely logical while "то" is an emotive one.

Answer (score 5):

Важно: я не профессиональный лингвист и объясняю простыми словами. Возможны ошибки. =)

Здесь "-то" вносит оттенок смысла "в отличие от кого-то", "несмотря на что-то" :

> Внешне баба Тома была похожа на классическую русскую бабушку, но я-то знал, что была у неё за плечами какая-то непростая судьба.

Другой человек, посмотрев на бабушку, воспринял бы ее как простую русскую бабушку. Но я знал, что ее жизнь была очень непростой.

> У нас-то мир и спокойствие, мы нужны всем!

В отличие от кого-то еще, у нас - мир и спокойствие. Кто эти "кто-то еще", должно быть понятно из контекста.

> Ничего-то нам было не известно

Здесь "-то" добавляет смысл "совсем ничего". Сравните "nothing" и "nothing at all". А еще, как мне кажется, этим выражается эмоциональное отношение говорящего - а именно, сожаление или досада. Просто "ничего нам не было известно" такой эмоциоанльной окраски не имеет.

Answer (score 2):

Частица `то` может использоваться не только для указания неопределённости, но и для придания большей эмоциональности. В ваших примерах - для подчёркивания и усиления (`я-то` == `именно я`, `у нас-то` == `именно у нас / или, например, у нас` и так далее.)